# How to extract data from Tkinter browse button in a convinient format

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a GUI with the `Tkinter` module in Python. I'm trying to get data from a tab separated file in a convenient format, when opened with a Browse button. I now have the following code, which saves my data in one long string (when called using `data.get()`), including `\t`'s and `\n`'s. Is there a convenient way to get my data immediately into a `pandas` dataframe, instead of filtering out empty lines, finding the header, separating at `\t`'s etc.?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

def browse_file():
    file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
    path.set(file.name)
    if file:
        data.set(file.read())

root = Tk()
path = StringVar()
data = StringVar()
Entry(root, textvariable=path, width=50).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(root, text="Browse", command=browse_file).pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Edit:

### Sample data

```
Average readings / Time between readings = 1 / 0.10

Rel Time    X1  Y1(Volts)

0.812   0.000000E+0 3.652836E-5
1.130   1.000000E-5 8.870999E-3
1.435   2.000000E-5 1.785118E-2
```

Comment: How about `read_table()`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files.  Post a sample of your data if you need more help.

Comment: @7stud Good suggestion. The data looks better if I do `data.set(pd.read_table(file))`, but it is still returned as a string. I guess there is no way around this, since you can not put it directly into a `pandas` dataframe, by declaring `data=pd.DataFrame()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data looked like this:

```
data = """
Average readings / Time between readings = 1 / 0.10

Rel_Time\tX1\tY1(Volts)

0.812\t0.000000E+0\t3.652836E-5
1.130\t1.000000E-5\t8.870999E-3
1.435\t2.000000E-5\t1.785118E-2
"""
```

then you could do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import io

data = """
Average readings / Time between readings = 1 / 0.10

Rel_Time\tX1\tY1(Volts)

0.812\t0.000000E+0\t3.652836E-5
1.130\t1.000000E-5\t8.870999E-3
1.435\t2.000000E-5\t1.785118E-2
"""

df = pd.read_table(
        io.StringIO(data),
        header = 1,
        index_col = 0,
        dtype = np.float64
    )

print(df)

--output:--
               X1  Y1(Volts)
Rel_Time                    
0.812     0.00000   0.000037
1.130     0.00001   0.008871
1.435     0.00002   0.01785
```

If that's the sort of thing you want, then you need to figure out how to get your actual data into that format.

Comment: Yes this works if you want to import the data, but how to combine this as efficient as possible when combining with the `tkFileDialog`.

Comment: @Roald, `read_table()` can be given a file path as an argument, which is what `askopenfilename()` returns.